# Error Establishing A Connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I downloaded the files from my site so that I can edit the files in my localhost however I can't import the database that I downloaded from the Live site and this is the error. How can I fixed this?

SQL query:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `island_commentmeta`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  `island_commentmeta` ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1046 - No database selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Importing you need to click on the database in which you need to import and then click on import button. I'm sure you will get rid of this error then.

Comment: So I have this file that I downloaded from my live site and that is the file that I'm trying to import but then the error above occurs.

Comment: Click on localhost or whatever you hostname is. There on the left hand side you'll see the list of database names. Click on the one you want to import your .sql file to and then hit import button.

Comment: Oh yeah! I get that. I need to create the database first in my localhost :) I forgot zzz

Comment: @JohnRobertson: That's hilarious ;)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the select the db

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.island_commentmeta ;
```

Comment: The database works fine on LIVE site and I downloaded it and as I import it to my localhost it doesn't work and refer to the error above. I can't change the table because firstly I can't Import it what should I do?